# How can I run anacron in user mode?

Tags: users, scheduled, anacron

I would like to set up a scheduled task via `anacron` but I would like to do so in user mode. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you want the task to run in user mode, you can do what i did and just prepend `sudo -u <user>` before the task in `anacrontab`

Comment: Also answered here: http://serverfault.com/questions/172989/user-specific-anacrontab/172994 and here's a nice fully written up solution: http://akeil.net/posts/user-controlled-anacron.html

Comment: This answer is very simple: https://askubuntu.com/a/1105580/132783 Just switch to the user inside the anacron specific job.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can set up a separate anacron instance to run in user mode:

1. Create a `.anacron` folder in your home directory and in it two subfolders, `etc` and `spool`:

   ```bsh
   mkdir -p ~/.anacron/{etc,spool}
   ```
2. Create a new file `~/.anacron/etc/anacrontab` with contents similar to the following:

   ```bsh
   # /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

   # See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

   SHELL=/bin/bash
   PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

   # period  delay  job-identifier  command
   1         10     testjob         test.sh
   ```
3. Add the following line to your crontab using `crontab -e`:

   ```bsh
   @hourly /usr/sbin/anacron -s -t $HOME/.anacron/etc/anacrontab -S $HOME/.anacron/spool
   ```

Comment: Just to confirm, this runs the specified script as the user, so a `whoami` in the script will give the user name?

Comment: hm yeah, on further inspection I don't see why not...

Comment: I think you need to run `anacron` periodically; it seems to run once then quit. The system's anacron is called once every hour. I suppose a similar strategy would work here, i.e. call the user `anacron` from the user `crontab`.

Comment: @Sparhawk agreed, in particular Ubuntu 15.10 anacron uses both `/etc/apm/event.d/anacron` and `/etc/init/anacron.conf` to take care of restarts.

Comment: You need to run anacron hourly with a cron job, e.g. `01 * * * * /usr/sbin/anacron -t /home/user/.anacron/etc/anacrontab -S /home/user/.anacron/spool`

Comment: This won't work if the user has an encrypted home directory. I've replaced that last `crontab -e` command with an entry in my `~/.profile` instead.

Comment: @Razor but my `.profile` entry didn't get me anywhere: `anacron` didn't run at login. I had to `sudo` everytime to do this, requiring my password

Comment: @Glutanimate thank you for this! It has been driving me crazy for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (thanks), but I didn't use the last step given in the answer:

> Then add the following line to your `~/.profile`:

I'm using Ubuntu Studio 12.10 Quantal and in my case instead of that last step I put that one liner here:
“Applications Menu” → “Settings” → “Settings Manager” then in the Settings Manager under “Session and Startup” then the “Application Autostart” tab.

This is for those of us that are GUI users, because `~/.profile` is only sourced by bash when it starts a log-in interactive shell (even `~/bashrc` is not so useful since that is only sourced when bash is starting an interactive shell).

Comment: Mmh, I am a GUI user myself and the line in `.profile` has always worked fine for me (Ubuntu 12.04 here).

Answer (score 0):

The anacrontab shown above has a problem: anacron looks for executables only in the directories specified in PATH. So it will not find test.sh.

A better solution is to use the command run-parts:

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# period  delay  job-identifier  command
1         10     dailyjob        run-parts ${HOME}/.anacron/daily/
```

This requires that we create the directory daily:

```
mkdir -p ~/.anacron/{etc,spool,daily}
```

run-parts will not execute scripts with '.' in the name, such as "test.sh", so rename the script to, for example, "my-test".

There is yet another wrinkle: If the computer does not run 24/7, then one does not have control over at what time the daily script is run. I have a web scraping script that I want to be run at about 11 am, or later during the day. I fix this problem by scheduling the web scraping job in the "at" facility (sudo apt install at).

So I have a script daily/crawl which looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

preferred_time="11:15"
scheduled_time="${preferred_time}"
preferred_time_as_number="${preferred_time/:/}"
current_time_as_number=$(date +%H%M)
if [ "${current_time_as_number}" -ge "${preferred_time_as_number}" ]; then
    scheduled_time="NOW"
fi
at -M -f "${HOME}/bin/crawl-dagpris.sh" "${scheduled_time}"
```