# Why anacron does not call the crontab user files?

Tags: users, cron, locate, anacron, updatedb

I want a special command to be lauched everyday, but dont want to put it in the /etc/cron.d/ because its a user specific user!

```
pg@pipoTower: ~$ crontab -l
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 0 * * * updatedb -l 0 -o ~/.externalharddisk.db -U /var/autofs/removable/usbData
```

The `crontab -e` command which puts the file in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/userName`

but dont know why its not called by anacron....

```
usr@Tower: ~/$ cat /etc/anacrontab 
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
1       5       cron.daily      run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7       10      cron.weekly     run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly        15      cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
```

Comment: Let's start with this: run 'sudo crontab -u [username] -l' and tell me if the cron job is there, please.

Comment: anacrontab is not the program that calls the files under `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`, cron is. anacrontab is the program that calls whatever is in cron.daily, .weekly, and .monthly.

Comment: @Alaa Thx for your confirmation, but doesn't help me... how do I do it for `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/` to be called by anacron?

Comment: Is there a reason you want anacron to call the files in that location? Because `cron` automatically calls those files. In your question, you have already created a crontab for the user `pg` to run that `updatedb` command every day at midnight, right? Then that's it, your cronjob is functional now. If you want to check if it's working, do `cat /var/log/syslog | grep CRON | grep updatedb`, you should see a line(s) like `CRON[###]: (pg) CMD (updatedb -l 0 -o ~/.externalharddisk.db -U /var/autofs/removable/usbData)`. If you do, then your cronjob is working.

Comment: @Alaa reason is if my computer isn't tuned on.... its a workstation, not a server ;-)

Comment: `cron` and `anacron` will never turn on the computer to run cronjobs. From my search, what you're looking for is to combine the tool [`rtcwake`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/rtcwake) and cron. `rtcwake` can be used to suspend your machine and to specify a time for it to wake up automatically. You can read [this](http://www.osnews.com/story/24111/), [this](http://hajimu.org/?p=2936), and [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/121241/how-to-make-your-linux-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run anacron in user mode?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235089/how-can-i-run-anacron-in-user-mode)

Answer (score 11):

I've found two workarounds for this...

**Option 1: Have cron.daily script run as non-root user**

Scripts in `/etc/cron.daily` will run as root, but root doesn't need a password to run as someone else.  So put a script there that does something like this:

`su myuser -c "/home/myuser/dostuff.sh"`

The main drawback if you need to be root to set this up.

**Option 2: Set up a personal anacron**

Create your own anacron script directories, eg `~/.anacron/daily`, `~/.anacron/weekly` and `~/.anacron/monthly`.  Put your daily scripts in the daily directory.

Then create your own anacrontab file, eg `~/.anacron/anacrontab`. And make it say this:

```
1   5   cron.daily  run-parts --report /home/myuser/.anacron/daily
7   10  cron.weekly run-parts --report /home/myuser/.anacron/weekly
@monthly    15  cron.monthly    run-parts --report /home/myuser/.anacron/monthly
```

Also make a spool directory for your anacron task, eg `~/.anacron/spool`.

Finally you need make anacron run. Use a frequent cron job for this.  Run `crontab -e` and add

```
* * * * * /usr/sbin/anacron -t /home/myuser/.anacron/anacrontab -S /home/myuser/.anacron/spool
```

This will run anacron with your config every minute and if a job is due anacron will run it.  You can make it less frequent if you like, every hour might be good enough for most users.