# Run /etc/cron.daily from specific user

Tags: cron, anacron

Do I properly understand that it is not possible to run `/etc/cron.daily/my` from arbitrary user, it will be run only from `root` according to `/etc/crontab`?

Can I drop root privilege to specific user in my cron scrip instead?

It is better to place cron job into `/etc/cron.d`? Like:

```
$ cat /etc/cron.d/my
5 0 * * *  user  test -x /usr/bin/my && /usr/bin/my -cfg /etc/my.cfg
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are right, the jobs in `/etc/cron.daily` (and weekly/monthly, etc.) are always
executed as user `root` but you can simply swith the user from within the script
and call that very script again as that other user, including all supplied
arguments (although there won't be any in a `cron.daily` job):

File `/etc/cron.daily/my`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

# If started as root, then re-start as user "gavenkoa":
if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
    exec sudo -H -u gavenkoa $0 "$@"
    echo "This is never reached.";
fi

echo "This runs as user $(id -un)";
# prints "gavenkoa"

exit 0;
```

When the script is started as user `root` it will detect so and
re-execute *itself* via `sudo -H -u gavenkoa`, that is: as 
user `gavenkoa`. This requires no special entries in `/etc/sudoers`
because `root` is always allowed to switch to any user.

The `exec` *replaces* the current process with the new `sudo …` call
and never returns. That's why you don't need an `else` clause.

Comment: As I understand `sudo` isn't POSIX utils. Is `su` available in all UNIXes?

Comment: @gavenkoa We are talking about Ubuntu, aren't we? There `sudo` is always installed. But if you prefer `su` instead, you can of course replace the `sudo` call with `su` but be aware that it's more complicated to pass the arguments `"$@"` to `su`, see [Pass arguments to a command run by another user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156343/251553) over on U&L.